# Gnome3 Window Decorations Disappeared on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I am using gdm (Gnome Display Manager) and gnome3 (regular, not classic) on Ubuntu 16.04.

After switching from Unity, I am not able to see any window decorations on all windows.

I cannot resize the windows correctly and I have seen no option on how to turn this on in the [Compiz Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) and in the [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/GnomeTweakTool?action=show&redirect=GnomeTweakTool).

Here's a screenshot of the issue, as you can see there is no window border.

[image: missing window decorations in gnome3 on ubuntu 16.04]

Comment: Is your system fully updated?

Comment: @CelticWarrior what versions of things should be I looking for?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I just did an update, what would the full-upgrade do if I'm 16.04 LTS and have upgraded gnome3 to the latest version?

Comment: Whenever installing software, particularly from third party PPAs and especially DEs regardless of where they come from, you should have the system fully updated. `apt upgrade` usually does that, `apt full-upgrade` also installs pending packages and is often used by the Update tool (use the GUI if you want, the end result is the same, cli is faster).

Comment: it didn't do anything, my system is fully upgraded. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install gnome-tweak-tool

`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

In the appearance section, reset GTK+, Icons, Cursor

[image]

Comment: that fixed the window decorations, the cursor and icons still appear small in some apps (maybe I have to restart?)

Comment: i did a logout/login. otherwise i had issues with font rendering etc.