# Gnome 3.24 shows no window border and mismatch full size windows

Tags: unity, gnome, window-decoration

I am Unity only and I want to give Gnome a try on Ubuntu 16.10 (edit :now, i switched to 17.04, and the issue is the same). I installed gnome with `apt install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. I kept `LightDM` as single display manager.

When login to either `gnome classic` or `gnome`, many windows, but not all, no longer have borders : I can't resize them, and they look weired. Also, rounded corners shows black pixels.  (when login with gnome (Wayland)` session I only got a black screen. But that's another issue)

Moreover, full screen windows (e.g. `Firefox`) doesn't match and we can see a few pixels of my background above and below window's titles.

I guess this have something to do with `client-side decorations`, or maybe `Compiz` ?

I've seen similar things [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448204/how-do-i-add-a-border-around-windows-but-keep-the-current-theme) on older distributions. [This issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/877270/458410) seems to be a little different.

#### Question :

I don't want to mess up with Unity, because I'm very skeptical about sticking to gnome, especially after experiencing such issues in the very first moments.

Can I fix that bug and keep both `gnome` and `unity` working properly ?

#### Screenshots :

[image: Firefox window title on full screen]
[image: Terminal and settings window corners]

#### Solutions Tried:

- [Disable client-side-decorations](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/gtk3-nocsd-module-to-disable-client.html) with `gtk3-nocsd` :

  `apt install gtk3-nocsd`
- switch from `lightdm` to `gdm3` (but now, I do can login with `Wayland`)

Comment: theming issue?  switch to adwaita for GNOME-Shell and Ambiance for Unity?  Do you have any locally installed versions of those themes in  ~/.themes ?

Comment: @fossfreedom Great ! I switched from `Ambiance` to `Adwaita`, with `gnome-tweak-tool`, and everything looks fine now. Post a clean complete answer and you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggestion here is to use themes that are best suited for the desktop-environment that you are running.

The default theme for Unity called Ambiance is the theme you should use for Unity itself.

When switching to GNOME-Shell, the default theme you should use is Adwaita.

Third-party themes can also be used - their support for various desktop-environments can vary.  Examples that you can use in both include Adapta and Arc-Theme (available in the 16.10/17.04 repo).

Its also worth double-checking that you have not got locally installed themes in `~/.themes` - themes are GTK+ specific so if your theme is not compatible with the version of GTK+ you are running on, then odd stuff like you described can occur.

GNOME-Tweak-Tool (available from GNOME-Software) can be used to switch themes in GNOME-Shell; unity-tweak-tool can be used in Unity if you are using third-party themes.

[image]

---

[How to install themes with GNOME tweak tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101651/how-to-install-themes-with-gnome-tweak-tool)

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for Ambiance and Radiance themes with Gnome, coming in Ubuntu 17.10, but available now : [Fix Ubuntu Light Themes](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/319719129/light-themes_16.10+17.10.20170515.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb). ([Source: OMG Ubuntu !](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/install-improved-ambiance-gnome-theme))

[image]

Comment: Came too late, but this is great!